# The line integration of $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{(z+a)(\bar z+\bar a)}$, where $|z|=1$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|a|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Q. If $a \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|a|<1$, then the value of $$\frac{\left(1-|a|^{2}\right)}{\pi} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{|d z|}{|z+a|^{2}},$$
where $\Gamma$ is the simple closed curve $|z|=1$ taken with the positive orientation, is...

My attempt: I started with $z=e^{i \theta}$ to get $dz=iz d\theta$ and thereby $|dz|=d \theta$, then $$\frac{\left(1-|a|^{2}\right)}{\pi} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{|d z|}{|z+a|^{2}}=\frac{\left(1-|a|^{2}\right)}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{(z+a)\overline{(z+a)}}=\frac{\left(1-|a|^{2}\right)}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{(z+a){(\bar z+\bar a)}}$$ How to proceed further.

Comment: you can use residues?

Comment: Maybe you can separate by partial fractions and some way use the Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: $(z+a)(\overline{z}+\overline{a})= |z|^2+z\overline{a}+\overline{z}a +|a|^2=1+z\overline{a}+\overline{z}a +|a|^2$ and $d\theta=-i\overline{z}dz$ right?

Comment: I think  that your answer is here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549821/value-of-i-frac-1-a2%cf%80-int-gamma-frac-dz-z-a-2-ove?rq=1